# Calculate percentage change in one column, first to last year

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I want to calculate a percentage change between the first year `2015` and the last year `2017` as one value for each `city`.

Here's my reproducable example where the last column `perct_change_2015_2017` is the desired output. How do I do this in R for a whole bunch of cities? Preferably in dplyr.

**EDIT** with the right percentage change figures

```
example <- structure(list(city = c("Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", 
"Rotterdam", "Rotterdam", "Rotterdam"), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), value = c(30L, 35L, 46L, 23L, 19L, 
17L), perct_change_2015_2017 = c(0.5333333333, 0.5333333333, 
0.5333333333, -0.2608695652, -0.2608695652, -0.2608695652)), .Names = c("city", 
"year", "value", "perct_change_2015_2017"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(city = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), perct_change_2015_2017 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("city", "year", "value", "perct_change_2015_2017"
    )), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

example

 A tibble: 6 x 4
  city       year value perct_change_2015_2017
  <chr>     <int> <int>                  <dbl>
1 Amsterdam  2015    30                  0.533
2 Amsterdam  2016    35                  0.533
3 Amsterdam  2017    46                  0.533
4 Rotterdam  2015    23                 -0.260
5 Rotterdam  2016    19                 -0.260
6 Rotterdam  2017    17                 -0.260
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first` and `last` function could be useful. It is also important to use the `arrange` function to make sure the values are in the right order.

```
library(dplyr)

example2 <- example %>%
  arrange(city, year) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(perct_change_2015_2017 = (last(value) - first(value))/first(value)) %>%
  ungroup()
example2
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   city       year value perct_change_2015_2017
#   <chr>     <int> <int>                  <dbl>
# 1 Amsterdam  2015    30                  0.533
# 2 Amsterdam  2016    35                  0.533
# 3 Amsterdam  2017    46                  0.533
# 4 Rotterdam  2015    23                 -0.261
# 5 Rotterdam  2016    19                 -0.261
# 6 Rotterdam  2017    17                 -0.261
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(city = c("Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", 
"Rotterdam", "Rotterdam", "Rotterdam"), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), value = c(30L, 35L, 46L, 23L, 19L, 
17L)), .Names = c("city", "year", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(city = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), perct_change_2015_2017 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("city", "year", "value", "perct_change_2015_2017"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This gives `perct_change_minYear_maxYear`, not 2015_2017.

Comment: @zx8754, so it answers the question in the title and is more generally useful.

Comment: @zx8754 You are right. If there are other years, it will not be percentage change in 2015 to 2017.

Comment: @Gregor Agree, yours answer question in the body... and now OP changed the output.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know abt the `first()` and `last()` function .

Answer (score 5):

This method will always use `2015` and `2017`, regardless of how many years there are. I prefer www's solution using `first` and `last` generally, but if you have more years and want these specific years, here is how to do it.

```
example %>% group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(perct_change_2015_2017 =
    (value[year == 2017] - value[year == 2015]) / value[year == 2015]
  )
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   city [2]
#        city  year value perct_change_2015_2017
#       <chr> <int> <int>                  <dbl>
# 1 Amsterdam  2015    30              0.5333333
# 2 Amsterdam  2016    35              0.5333333
# 3 Amsterdam  2017    46              0.5333333
# 4 Rotterdam  2015    23             -0.2608696
# 5 Rotterdam  2016    19             -0.2608696
# 6 Rotterdam  2017    17             -0.2608696
```

Comment: Both are great solutions, I'll upvote yours and accept @www